# Regarding jQuery buttons, is it possible to make one smaller than the regular size?

Tags: css

On a web page I am using a jquery button.  This code produces the button:

```
<button type="submit">Update</button>
```

This is how it looks, it is a little too big for the line:
[image]

Is there an inline CSS statement that can make this smaller?  Inline is preferred is possible.

Thank you

Comment: Why is inline preferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" style="padding: 0; font-size: small;">Update</button>
```